# Adding HTML to the end of an element. No errors; no HTML added

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I have an ordered list with the class `flex-control-nav` and I am trying to append it with html. I have tried add(), append() and html() to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

JS:

```
 $('.flex-control-nav').add('<li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#youtubeModal"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x1000" /></li> ')
```

full js:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        //set product color as variable
        var productColor = '<%- product.data["product.product_color"].value[0].text %>';
        // Remove empty p tags in markdown
        $('p').each(function(index, item) {
            if($.trim($(item).text()) === "") {
                $(item).slideUp(); // $(item).remove();
            }
        });

        $('.specs ul li a').attr('target', '_blank')

        // Auto Attr
        var attrText = "<%- product.uid %>";
        var attr = $(this).attr('alt');
        $('img').each(function () {
            var $img = $(this);
            if (typeof attr == typeof undefined || attr == false) {
                $img.attr('alt', 'dome-' + attrText + '-image');
            } else {
                $img.removeAttr("alt");
                $img.attr('alt', 'dome-' + attrText + '-image');
            }
        })

        //Hamburger Menu
        var width = $(window).width();
        $(window).on('resize', function() {
            if ( width <= 992 ) {
                    $("#primary-menu-trigger").addClass('side-panel-trigger');
                    $("#hide-on-mobile").css('display', 'hide');
                    $("#icon-color").css('color', productColor);
                }
            }).trigger("resize");

            $('.flex-control-nav').add('<li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#youtubeModal"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x1000" /></li> ') // add youtube to thumb slider

        }) //jQuery

    </script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="fslider" data-arrows="false" data-animation="fade" data-thumbs="true">
                            <div class="flexslider">
                                <div class="slider-wrap">
                                    <div class="slide" data-thumb="<%= product.data["product.buy-img"].value.main.url %>"><img src="<%= product.data["product.buy-img"].value.main.url %>" alt="Slider 1"></div>
                                    <div class="slide" data-thumb="<%= product.data["product.thumbgallery1"].value.main.url %>"><img src="<%= product.data["product.thumbgallery1"].value.main.url %>" alt="Slider 1"></div>
                                    <div class="slide" data-thumb="<%= product.data["product.thumbgallery2"].value.main.url %>"><img src="<%= product.data["product.thumbgallery2"].value.main.url %>" alt="Slider 2"></div>
                                    <div class="slide" data-thumb="<%= product.data["product.thumbgallery3"].value.main.url %>"><img src="<%= product.data["product.thumbgallery3"].value.main.url %>" alt="Slider 3"></div>
                                    <div class="slide" data-thumb="<%= product.data["product.thumbgallery4"].value.main.url %>"><img src="<%= product.data["product.thumbgallery4"].value.main.url %>" alt="Slider 4"></div>
                                    <div class="slide" data-thumb="<%= product.data["product.thumbgallery5"].value.main.url %>"><img src="<%= product.data["product.thumbgallery5"].value.main.url %>" alt="Slider 4"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

The ordered list is generated with jquery by the plugin.

Thanks ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.add()` is a selector modifier, not a function to add HTML content.

You want to use `.after()`:

`$('.flex-control-nav').after('<li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#youtubeModal"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x1000" /></li> ')`

`.after()` in this case adds the `li` immediately after *each* `.flex-control-nav`.

If you want the element added at the end of each `.flex-control-nav` content, use `.append()`.

Also, it does not appear that your the HTML you provided has an element with class `flex-control-nav`.